Search for a pattern in a string array
Let's assume I have the following array:
string[] arr = ["Off", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty"];

I want to check if the array has the two or more "Off", then followed by a "Duty", then followed by two or more "Off".
Currently, I am doing a loop, checking if the value is "Duty", then going back two values and check if both are "Off", then going forward and check if next two are "Off". It works, but I feel it can be better:
for (int i = 0; i < roster.Length; i++)
{
    if (roster[i] == "Duty")
    {
       if (i > 1 && i < roster.Length - 2) 
       {
           if (roster[i-2] == "Off" && roster[i-1] == "Off" && roster[i+1] == "Off" && roster[i+2] == "Off") 
           {
                return true;
           }
       }
    }
}


Doesn't seem too bad to me, though you could consider running the outer loop from 2  to roster.Length-2 - that would eliminate the need for the middle if.

@500-InternalServerError I need it to start from 0 because I am doing other checks as well..

Why does your question not mention that, then?

Try this:
     string[] arr = new string[] { "Off", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty" };

     string s = String.Join( ",", arr );

     bool found = s.Contains( "Off,Off,Duty,Off,Off" );

     Console.WriteLine( found );
     Console.ReadKey();



I want to check if the array has the two or more "Off", then followed by a "Duty", then followed by two or more "Off".

Becuase the number of "Duty" you want to find is exactly one, you can simplify this by saying you want to know if there exists a sequence of exactly two "Off", a "Duty" and two "Off". You don't really care about more "Off" before or after because it makes no difference.
So you can simply use IndexOf with a Span
string[] arr = ["Off", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Duty", "Off", "Off", "Duty"];

string[] contained = ["Off", "Off", "Duty", "Off", "Off"];

var doesContain = arr.AsSpan().IndexOf(contained) != -1;

dotnetfiddle
Unfortunately you can't (yet) use a custom comparer (such as StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) with this method.

You can make delimited string from the array. Then you can use regex to check if there is a match of this pattern inside the string
